# What are the best practices for passing multiple variables to a function using PHP

Tags: php, function

I have a function that takes 5 parameters, and as the application grew we needed to add few more parameters which ended up in 9 parameters with 4 of them having default values.

I was wondering is it better to pass parameters like this or use an array?

I prefer to have it like this

```
fun(array(
     'par1' => 'x',
     'par2' => 'y',
     .....
    )
 )
```

Insted of

```
func($par1, $par2, $par3, ...);
```

What do you think?

Comment: Passing array for multiple parameters would be good practice.

Comment: Better yet, define a class to be a parameter object.  That way if the parameters change you don't have to change *all* the calling code, just the object.  You can assign defaults and other business logic on the object.  Etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590860/passing-array-of-parameters-vs-individual-parameters-to-a-function-in-php

Comment: @HarshalMahajan, yes right. Array would be good solution for this.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan How will this be reflectable? How to use type hinting, how to generate phpdoc? The answer is: "There is no general answer, it depends on the use case." You need to balance reasons for and against it?

Comment: Often you can get away with arrays. You an also try to group several parameters together - often they are common attributes of an entity. Dumb example: if parameter 1 and 2 are the x and y coordinates, you can pass them together as a single point object.

Comment: @hek2mgl no i don't think so but this will reduce the chance of missing the parameter and would be well structured code.otherwise to pass the `object` of class in function also the best option.

Comment: +1 as this is an important question that is highly design related. It's good to ask yourself questions like this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Highly depends on the use case.

But here are some solutions to this problem.

---

#### Fixed Order

If the order is somewhat fixed and you never have a need to change it, then:

```
<?php

function fn($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5, $a6 = null, $a7 = "foo", $a8 = "bar", array $a9 = array()) {}
```

**Pros**

- Self documenting
- Type hinting
- Default values

**Cons**

- Fixed order

---

#### Array

If on the other hand the order is somewhat different all the time, use the array thingy.

```
<?php

function fn($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5, array $optional = array()) {}

fn("", "", "", "", "", array("arg9" => false));
```

**Pros**

- Easy to use
- No fixed order

**Cons**

- Not self documenting
- Costly to validate

---

#### Parameter Object

A parameter object is of course a valid solution as well, but impractical to handle:

```
<?php

class Args {

  public $arg5 = "foo";

  public $arg6 = "bar";

  public $arg7 = null;

  public $arg8 = array();

  public $arg9 = true;

}

function fn($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5, \Args $optional = null) {}

// Now comes the impractical part.
$optional = new Args();
$optional->arg9 = false;
fn("", "", "", "", "", $optional);
```

**Pros**

- Self documenting
- No fixed order

**Cons**

- Highly impractical
- Costly to validate

---

#### Array to Parameter Object

You could mix the two approaches:

```
<?php

class Args {

  public $arg5 = "foo";

  public $arg6 = "bar";

  public $arg7 = null;

  public $arg8 = array();

  public $arg9 = true;

  public __construct($args) {
    foreach ($args as $property => $value) {
      $this->"set{$property}"($value);
    }
  }

  public function setArg5($value) {
    if (is_string($value) === false) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException;
    }
    $this->arg5 = $value;
  }

  // and so on ...

}

function fn($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5, array $optional = null) {
  if (isset($optional)) {
    $optional = new Args($optional);
  }
  // ...
}

fn("", "", "", "", "", array("arg9" => false));
```

**Pros**

- Easy validation
- Separation of concern
- Easy to pass along
- Easy to handle
- Possible to document the API

**Cons**

- Still not possible to document it as good as the fixed args approach
- Costly to validate

---

#### Variadics

There's a new feature in PHP 5.6 that you might find useful, [variadics](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics):

```
<?php

function fn($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5, ...$optional) {}
```

**Pros**

- Very fast
- Allows to build special APIs (e.g. database prepared statement binding)

**Cons**

- Not easily documented
- Costly to validate

---

#### Named Parameters

And we might see [named parameters](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) in the future.

Answer (score 8):

#### You're attacking the wrong problem.

Passing 9 parameters to a function is a clear [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell):

> *Too many parameters*: a long list of parameters in a procedure or
> function makes readability and code quality worse.

With that many parameters, there's also a good chance that you violate:

> *Long method*: a method, function, or procedure that has grown too
> large.

Creating an arbitrary `array` that groups together those parameters won't solve the *real* issue. It can make your code somewhat more readable and less vulberable to small problems like omitting a parameter (`$arg1, $arg2, $arg4`), but not a real solution.

#### What you should do instead:

Figure out why the function needs that many parameters, then fix that issue.

- If the single function has too many reponsibilities: split it. You can do a single sequential split: One task after the another.
- If multiple parameters can be aggregated to a single entity, create an object for it (eg: x and y coordinates can be merged to a point. a rectangle can be described by two opposite corner points). Try to create something reusable, so it's sole purpose isn't just to be able to pass arguments to this single function.

There are a lot of techniques, reading a good article/book about (oo) *code refactoring* can give you some hints.

Comment: A code smell doesn't necessarily mean that you're doing something wrong, just that you should check if you might be doing something wrong. There are many valid reasons to ignore these recommendations, of course you have to be a good developer to know those.

Comment: In 1 word: yes. In a bit more: He's *probably* doing something wrong.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to invalidate your answer (on the contrary, I just +1 it). Just wanted to make sure that nobody thinks that code smells are like the Bible for some religious people.

Comment: It was all clear, no misunderstanding ;) As for the rest, there should be a big banner in front of the entrance of the Interweb (or Life for that matter) that nothing should be handled like the Bible by some religious people ;P